# Grammar question: becoming overweight themselves

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

I find a sentence below, and don't understand the grammar.

> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of becoming overweight themselves.

"becoming" is a gerund and "overweight" is an adjective. The problem is "themselves". Can anyone help me understand the grammatical structure of this sentence?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do phrases have objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reflexive pronoun can be used to give [emphasis](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/reflexive-pronouns#:%7E:text=Adding%20emphasis,it%20personally%2C%20not%20anybody%20else.).

> I locked the door myself.  (Emphsises ***I*** locked the door, not someone else!)

The reflexive pronoun should match the subject.

In this participle clause, the subject is understood to be "Children whose parents are overweight", and the emphatic reflexive pronoun adds rhetorical force to sentence:  ***They*** are at risk of becoming overweight.

Comment: Did you mean to say "*Children whose **parent is** overweight*"? Sounds like children only have one parent.

Answer (score 0):

**Function**
Adding the reflexive pronoun to the end of this sentence emphasizes that some repeated information is being applied to a new context.

Specifically, we are first told that *the parents* are overweight. "Overweight" is the repeated information. The word "themselves" emphasizes that *the child* is at risk of becoming overweight too.

**Grammar**
The word "themselves" is an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction), which means it doesn't have a normal part of the grammar of a sentence, like direct object or anything like that. This makes it hard for learners to parse, especially because English uses these constructions so rarely. Since it isn't part of the normal structure of the sentence, it doesn't need to be in any particular place in the sentence, and can be omitted:

> Children whose parents are overweight are ***themselves*** at a higher risk of becoming overweight.
> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk ***themselves*** of becoming overweight.
> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of becoming overweight ***themselves***.
> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of becoming overweight __________.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sentence is still fairly clear without *themselves.*  Adding *themselves* has a similar purpose to adding *also:* it calls the reader's attention to the fact that the overweight condition of the children is a separate and additional condition to that of the parents.  This is inherent in the meaning of the sentence without the additional word, but using the additional word helps the reader to understand it without having to stop and think about it.  Consider:

> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of becoming overweight.

> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of also becoming overweight.

> Children whose parents are overweight are at a higher risk of becoming overweight themselves.

The "also" version is a bit ambiguous; it leaves the question of whether it means "in addition to the parents" or "in addition to some other condition of the children that you didn't notice us mentioning earlier."  *Themselves* avoids this ambiguity.